# SQL - running total when data already grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, grouping, cumulative-sum

I am trying to do a running total for some data, and have seen the easy way to do it. However, I have already grouped some data and this is throwing off my code. I currently have dates and payment types, and the totals that it relates to.

What I have at the moment is:

```
create table #testdata
(
mdate date,
pmttype varchar(64),
totalpmtamt int
)

insert into #testdata
select getdate()-7, 'DD', 10
union
select getdate() -7, 'SO', 12
union
select getdate()-6, 'DD', 3
union
select getdate()-5, 'DD', 13
union
select getdate()-5, 'SO', 23
union
select getdate()-5, 'PO', 8
```

What I want to have is:

```
mdate       |  paymenttype  |  totalpmtamt  |  incrtotal
2016-08-29  |  DD           |  10           |  10
2016-08-29  |  SO           |  12           |  22
2016-08-30  |  DD           |  3            |  25
2016-08-31  |  DD           |  13           |  38
2016-08-31  |  SO           |  8            |  46
2016-08-31  |  PO           |  23           |  69
```

I've tried adapting other code I've found here into:

```
select  t1.mdate, 
        t1.pmttype,
        t1.totalpmtamt, 
        SUM(t2.totalpmtamt) as runningsum
     from #testdata t1
join #testdata t2 on t1.mdate >= t2.mdate and t1.pmttype >= t2.pmttype
group by t1.mdate, t1.pmttype, t1.totalpmtamt
order by t1.mdate
```

but all I get is

```
mdate       |  paymenttype  |  totalpmtamt  |  incrtotal
2016-08-29  |  DD           |  10           |  10
2016-08-29  |  SO           |  12           |  22
2016-08-30  |  DD           |  3            |  13
2016-08-31  |  DD           |  13           |  26
2016-08-31  |  SO           |  8            |  34
2016-08-31  |  PO           |  23           |  69
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You could use the simplier VALUES (...) when creating sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI standard way of doing a cumulative sum is:

```
select t.*, sum(totalpmtamt) over (order by mdate) as runningsum
from #testdata t
order by t.mdate;
```

Not all databases support this functionality.

If your database doesn't support that functionality, I would go for a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.totalpmtamt)
        from #testdata t2
        where t2.mdate <= t.mdate
       ) as runningsum
from #testdata
order by t.mdate;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I added in pmtttype to the over(order by mdate) which broke it down by individual row, not just grouping the dates together. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query for the desired result (for SQL Server).

```
with cte_1
     as
     (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by mdate  ) RNO
     FROM #testdata)
     SELECT mdate,pmttype,totalpmtamt,(select sum(c2.totalpmtamt)
        from cte_1 c2
        where c2.RNO <= c1.RNO
       ) as incrtotal
     FROM cte_1 c1
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: I upvoted your entry, but you should order by mdate not select 1.

Comment: @cetin yes. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @testdata TABLE
    (
      mdate DATE ,
      pmttype VARCHAR(64) ,
      totalpmtamt INT
    );

INSERT  INTO @testdata
        ( mdate, pmttype, totalpmtamt )
VALUES  ( GETDATE() - 7, 'DD', 10 ),
        ( GETDATE() - 7, 'SO', 12 ),
        ( GETDATE() - 6, 'DD', 3 ),
        ( GETDATE() - 5, 'DD', 13 ),
        ( GETDATE() - 5, 'SO', 23 ),
        ( GETDATE() - 5, 'PO', 8 );

SELECT  *,
        SUM(totalpmtamt) OVER ( ORDER BY mdate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )
        AS RunningTotal
FROM    @testdata t;
```